# Cloning the testing branch on git

Tags: git, github

I have been told that development takes place in the "testing" branch of some XYZ git tree:

`https://git.develop.org/def/pqr/abc/xyz.git/`

The above link is an imaginary/hypothetical git link related to Linux kernel.

So how do I clone the **testing** branch on my local laptop?
Will the following command suffice?:

`git clone https://git.develop.org/def/pqr/abc/xyz.git/`

What if it clones another branch ? for example `master`. Do i need to change to testing branch **explicitly** using `git checkout ...`

**OR** is there any other command to clone the **testing** branch **directly** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+branch

Comment: " I have been told that development takes place in the "testing" branch of some XYZ git tree"  .. well, it depends of each project politic, it's not an absolute rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this command:

```
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

[more](https://devconnected.com/how-to-clone-a-git-repository/)